# How to Draw Line between Source and Destination in Google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got the correct souce and destination latitude and longitude in map but I am able to drwa line between Source and destination but this line is strait line display in map between source and destination marker. Destination Latitide and Destination Longitude are fetch successfully from Server.

But I want to Draw line between source and destination Like this below.

[image]This is Example.
Google Map is also Display CurrectPosition of Source and Destination.
How can it Possible?

Please Guide me.
Please Help me.
Thank you.

My Code is,

```
public class Map extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap googleMap;

    SupportMapFragment fm;
    double myLat = 23.0137759;
    double destLat = 0.0;
    double myLng = 72.5158836;
    double destLng = 0.0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.navigate_to_me_map);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


            Intent intent = getIntent();

            destLat = intent.getDoubleExtra("latitude", 0.0);
            destLng = intent.getDoubleExtra("longitude", 0.0);

            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

            // Showing status
            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services

                int requestCode = 10;
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status,
                        this, requestCode);
                dialog.show();

            } else { 

                SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.fullmap);
                googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

                googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }


            googleMap
                    .setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new OnMyLocationChangeListener() {

                        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            myLat = location.getLatitude();
                            myLng = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    });

            drawRoutePath(strAddressOne);
        }
    }

    private void drawRoutePath(String searchText) {

        try {
            // find current address latlong and true than draw route
            // between to points or current loction and search
            // address


                googleMap.clear();

                if (myLat != 0 && myLng != 0) {

                    LatLng origin = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
                    drawMarker(origin);

                    LatLng dest = new LatLng(destLat, destLng);
                    drawMarker(dest);

                    Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                            .add(origin, dest).width(5).color(Color.RED));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Current Location does not found",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

            Log.e("Second ", "drawRoutePath errro " + e.toString());
        }

    }

    private void drawMarker(LatLng point) {
        // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

        // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
        markerOptions.position(point);

        // Adding marker on the Google Map

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).visible(true))
                .showInfoWindow();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                point.latitude, point.longitude), 6f));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `strAddressOne`??

Comment: @PiyushGupta strAddressOne is Fetch the Address from server but it is not useful in my code Because in this method I am getting destLat, destLng correctly.

Comment: @PiyushGupta Please Suggest me How to Draw Line Like this in Screenshot

Comment: You should go with this link http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Comment: @PiyushGupta I Reffered this Link but getting error but I will Second Time Check. and I will inform You what to do? Thanks

Comment: @PiyushGupta I am Not able to Draw Path Like this.

Comment: Any error did you get?

Comment: Yes I have got error

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: This is my Url , https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0331798,72.5246385&destination=38.0,-77.0&sensor=false and Get Response Like this, {
routes: [ ],
status: "ZERO_RESULTS"
}  so Give me force close

Comment: But right now there is no data and you didn't checked with that so it gives you error. Show logcat and parsing code.

Comment: Show your error atleast

Comment: Response ZERO_RESULTS and give Force close

Comment: When while you using this link code then?

Comment: Ya I wil tell you please Just 2 minutes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69887/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-reena).

Comment: I got you Error while using this Link https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=23.0331798,72.5246385&destination=38.0,-77.0&sensor=false

Comment: For your destination locations you need to use number atlease 6 after decimal.. Like current your dest lat is -77.0 but it should be -77.0512562 something like that. Also check this link in google map and check is it displaying route or not in browser.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the source code to draw a route between the source and destination :

```
public class MapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener  {

    private SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    ArrayList markerPoints;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private long UPDATE_INTERVAL = 15000;  /* 15 secs */
    private long FASTEST_INTERVAL = 5000; /* 5 secs */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

   // Marker marker;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_actionbar_maps);

        markerPoints = new ArrayList();
        mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    loadMap(map);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map Fragment was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void loadMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (map != null) {
            // Map is ready
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map Fragment was loaded properly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

                    // Already two locations
                    if(markerPoints.size()>1){
                        markerPoints.clear();
                        map.clear();
                    }

                    // Adding new item to the ArrayList
                    markerPoints.add(point);

                    // Creating MarkerOptions
                    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

                    // Setting the position of the marker
                    options.position(point);

/**
 * For the start location, the color of marker is GREEN and
 * for the end location, the color of marker is RED.
 */
                    if(markerPoints.size()==1){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                    }else if(markerPoints.size()==2){
                        options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
                    }

                    // Add new marker to the Google Map Android API V2
                    map.addMarker(options);

                    // Checks, whether start and end locations are captured
                    if(markerPoints.size() >= 2){
                        LatLng origin = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(0);
                        LatLng dest = (LatLng) markerPoints.get(1);

                        // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                        String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

                        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API
                        downloadTask.execute(url);
                    }

                }
            });


            // Now that map has loaded, let's get our location!
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            connectClient();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void connectClient() {
        // Connect the client.
        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() && mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity becomes visible.
    */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        connectClient();
    }

    /*
     * Called when the Activity is no longer visible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    /*
     * Handle results returned to the FragmentActivity by Google Play services
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // Decide what to do based on the original request code
        switch (requestCode) {

            case CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST:
            /*
             * If the result code is Activity.RESULT_OK, try to connect again
             */
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        break;
                }

        }
    }

// Fetches data from url passed


    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        // Check that Google Play services is available
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        // If Google Play services is available
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
            // In debug mode, log the status
            Log.d("Location Updates", "Google Play services is available.");
            return true;
        } else {
            // Get the error dialog from Google Play services
            Dialog errorDialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);

            // If Google Play services can provide an error dialog
            if (errorDialog != null) {
                // Create a new DialogFragment for the error dialog
                ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
                errorFragment.setDialog(errorDialog);
                errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Location Updates");
            }

            return false;
        }
    }



    /*
     * Called by Location Services when the request to connect the client
     * finishes successfully. At this point, you can request the current
     * location or start periodic updates
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
        // Display the connection status
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location != null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS location was found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
            map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            //marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.vehicle_marker)).flat(true).anchor(0.5f,0.5f));
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Current location was null, enable GPS on emulator!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Report to the UI that the location was updated

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
       /* if(marker == null){
           *//* marker.remove();*//*
            marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.vehicle_marker)));
        }

        marker.setPosition(latLng);
*/
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 16);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);



        String msg = "Updated Location: " +
                Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + "," +
                Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }



    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the connection to the location client
     * drops because of an error.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        if (i == CAUSE_SERVICE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (i == CAUSE_NETWORK_LOST) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network lost. Please re-connect.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Called by Location Services if the attempt to Location Services fails.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
         * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
         * services activity that can resolve error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this,
                        CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry. Location services not available to you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }


    // Define a DialogFragment that displays the error dialog
    public static class ErrorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        // Global field to contain the error dialog
        private Dialog mDialog;

        // Default constructor. Sets the dialog field to null
        public ErrorDialogFragment() {
            super();
            mDialog = null;
        }

        // Set the dialog to display
        public void setDialog(Dialog dialog) {
            mDialog = dialog;
        }

        // Return a Dialog to the DialogFragment.
        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return mDialog;
        }
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

// For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try{
// Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
// doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

// Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }


    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> >{

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

// Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

// Traversing through all the routes
            for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
                points = new ArrayList();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();


// Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

// Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for(int j=0;j <path.size();j++){
                    HashMap<String,String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

// Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(12);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);
                lineOptions.geodesic(true);

            }

// Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin,LatLng dest){

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin="+origin.latitude+","+origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination="+dest.latitude+","+dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin+"&"+str_dest+"&"+sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"+output+"?"+parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

// Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

// Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }
}
```

DirectionsJSONParser.java is given below :

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;



public class DirectionsJSONParser {

    /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list of lists containing latitude and longitude */
    public List<List<HashMap<String,String>>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");
                List path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){
                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l <list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                    routes.add(path);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

        return routes;
    }

    /**
     * Method to decode polyline points
     * Courtesy : http://jeffreysambells.com/2010/05/27/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps-direction-api-with-java
     * */
    private List decodePoly(String encoded) {

        List poly = new ArrayList();
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)),
                    (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }

        return poly;
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool Anup.. you are great.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use below library:

[Google-Directions-Android](https://github.com/jd-alexander/google-directions-android)

Comment: How to implementRoutingListener ?

Comment: Please check sample app of this library. It shows what you need.